# ttest between two datasets (e.g. cases and controls) for multiple bins

Tags: r, aggregate, tapply

I want to compare two datasets at differet bins. My input data is something like this:

```
 dataIn <- read.table(text =
"bin_slots  val_cases   val_controls
A   0.075   0.05
A   0.252   0.276
A   0.338   0.41
A   0.911   0.983
A   0.912   0.809
A   0.965   0.917
A   1   1
A   1   1
A   0   0
A   1   0.983
A   0.398   0.681
A   0.606   0.431
B   0.58    0.608
B   0.729   0.773
B   0.871   0.879
B   1   1
B   0.297   0.282
B   0.673   0.737
B   0.807   0.803
B   0.838   0.824
B   0.633   0.658"
, header = TRUE)
```

Using the above dataset i want to compare val_cases and val_controls for A and B and so on...Thus the output I would like to get can be like this:

```
bin_slots   p_value
A   0.416336774
B   0.066616655
```

Thanks a lot.
Best wishes,
Meraj

Comment: Are these actually paired data (i.e., each row is a matched pair of observations), or are the values for cases and controls not related? In either case, you probably want to use a two-way ANOVA, rather than making a lot of pairwise comparisons

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes it is paired data (pairing between cases and controls for each row).

Answer (score 0):

If the data are paired, you can either just analyze the difference (the same meaning as a paired t-test), as I do here, or add a column for "Individual" and run an ANOVA like I have below (treating individual as a random variable, for interpretation purposes). Here, I add a column for the difference (using `dplyr`), then run look at the output of the fitted model. For more control, save the result of `lm` and look at it with `aov` or `anova` and their methods.

```
ifPaired <-
  dataIn %>%
  mutate(diff = val_cases - val_controls)


lm(diff ~ bin_slots - 1
   , data = ifPaired) %>%
  summary()
```

Outputs (in part):

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
bin_slotsA -0.006917   0.024850  -0.278    0.784
bin_slotsB -0.015111   0.028695  -0.527    0.605
```

If, instead, the data are not paired, but rather just independent observations, convert the data to a long format (using `tidyr` here), then run an ANOVA with `bin` and `group` as predictors.

```
ifNotPaired <-
  dataIn %>%
  gather("group", "value", -bin_slots) %>%
  mutate(group = gsub("val_", "", group))

lm(value ~ group + bin_slots
   , data = ifNotPaired) %>%
  summary()
```

Outputs (in part):

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    0.61966    0.08110   7.641 2.87e-09 ***
groupcontrols  0.01043    0.09781   0.107    0.916    
bin_slotsB     0.09690    0.09882   0.981    0.333
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am interested to do paired-end ttest for my data. To clarify, each row of the input corresponds to a frequency bin and not each individual. In the first bin (designated as "A") there are 12 data points for cases and control each. I have hundreds of such bins (data points may vary for each bin) and I want to get p value for them. I am newbie to scripting. Thanks again!